# How to compare every value in a for loop?

Tags: php

I have a multidimentional array of 5 items and I want that my loop would compare it like:

```
1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2->1, 2->3, 2->4, 2->5......// so on and 5 -> 4 in the end.
```

The problem is that after my array $i value matches 1 and $j value matches 3, the unset is done and the $i value becomes 2 (which is correct) and $j value becomes 4 instead of 3. Could someone tell me why and what I'm doing wrong?

My loop is:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($myArray); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j <= count($myArray); $j++) {
            if (
                // condition 1
                && // condition 2
            ) {
                unset($myArray[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never remove array elements in a loop. You are reducing the total size of the array which results in unexpected behavior. Since you are killing an element, the element index of other elements will remain.

Comment: I think you're right. I've noticed that when there are 2-3 array elements, it works fine until I add some more to a database.

Comment: what are you trying to do? either I need more coffee or you need to give us some more detail.  Can you add exactly whats in `$myArray`?

Comment: @DevDonkey well it's a simple multidimensional array, nothing else.

Comment: Either you do not remove an element in the array, or you set initial length as a variable. When writing " $i <= count($array) " in a for loop it will compute the length every time. This is for performance purpose aswell

Comment: If you need to unset array elements in a loop - then iterate over the data _backwards_. Then the removal of an item does not affect any items that would be looped over _after_ it any more, so you don’t get problems with shifting indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the problem is when you unset the element in the array, you increment the counter of the loop `$i`. In this way, the elements of the array that are not configured are removed, this empty array position will be maintained, it will not be reordered, you will have to do it manually or using `array_values` ​​method.

In the last tour of the array, it will break because you are comparing the number of array elements as equal. You must use `index < count($array)`

The code would be like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($myArray); $j++) {
            if (
                // condition 1
                && // condition 2
            ) {
                unset($myArray[$i]);
                // $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  for ($i = 0; $i <= count($myArray); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j <= count($myArray); $j++) {
        if ($j!=$i)
        {
             if (
            // condition 1
            && // condition 2
        ) {
            unset($myArray[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = $myArray;
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($myArray); $i++)
{
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= count($myArray); $j++)
    {
        if (
            // condition 1
             && // condition 2
        )
        {
            unset($temp[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
print_r($temp);
```

Your result is in `$temp`. So here indexes wont get hampered, you actually are applying all operation on $temp and normally traversing $myArray.

Comment: That's the exact code that I have. I got my array in a variable and in the end - returning it. :(

Comment: Please update your question with the input array and expected output array to avoid further ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I do not know why nobody has yet advise to use nested foreach, since you all noticed there was a problem with array size.

```
foreach ($numbers as $number_horizontal_parsing) {
    foreach ($numbers as $number_vertical_parsing) {
        if ($number_horizontal_parsing != $number_vertical_parsing) {
            //do your stuff in your case it seems you want to compare both variables
        }
    }
}
```